# SQL SCCM database Server decrypt by certificate

Tags: sql, sql-server, sccm

I created certificate and database master key, as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/configmgr/protect/deploy-use/bitlocker/encrypt-recovery-data) guide

```
SELECT name FROM sys.symmetric_keys
##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##

SELECT name from sys.certificates WHERE name = 'BitLockerManagement_CERT'
BitLockerManagement_CERT
```

Now, I need to decrypt RecoveryKey from database dbo.RecoveryAndHardwareCore_Keys

```
OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY ##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##
DECRYPTION BY CERTIFICATE BitLockerManagement_CERT WITH PASSWORD = 'pass'
```

and am getting error:

> Global temporary keys are not allowed. You can only use local temporary keys.

**UPDATE:**

```
OPEN MASTER KEY
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = 'pass'

select RecoveryKey as 'encrypted', convert(nvarchar, decryptbykey(recoverykey)) from dbo.RecoveryAndHardwareCore_Keys
```

returns null

Comment: err.. but i do have only this global one, i just followed MS guide, is there any workaround ?

Comment: `OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY ##MS_DatabaseMasterKey##` is invalid and superfluous. The database master key is managed implicitly by SQL Server. If you want to open it explicitly (which is not normally necessary) use `OPEN MASTER KEY`.

Comment: If you get `NULL` from `DECRYPTBYKEY` then the key doesn't match. How was the value inserted in `RecoveryAndHardwareCore_Keys`? If you're following the docs, it isn't encrypting any column values using the key, it just demonstrates how to create a certificate and encrypt it using the key. It doesn't show how software will use the certificate, but most likely the `ENCRYPTBYCERT`/`DECRYPTBYCERT` functions will get involved. (Note that creating new certificates or keys when the data was already encrypted earlier will not work -- you'd need to restore the original ones from a separate backup.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved, no need to decrypt by certificate nor to open master key:

```
SELECT RecoveryAndHardwareCore.DecryptString(RecoveryAndHardwareCore_Keys.RecoveryKey, DEFAULT) AS RecoveryKey FROM RecoveryAndHardwareCore_Keys
```